# SapUi5 data binding on the radio button group is not working

Tags: javascript, data-binding, odata, sapui5

can some one please advise on the two-way data binding of the radio buttons with SAP UI5. In the data model I have an attribute called textType, it can return "Y" or "N", based on that I have to select the correspondent radio button

```
 <m:RadioButton text="yes" selected="{path:'/textType',formatter: function(val){ if(textType== 'Y') return true; }else{ return false} }"/><m:RadioButton text="No" selected="{Selected}"/>
```

however I am not able to set the value. I tried using the radiobutton group however no success

```
 <RadioButtonGroup buttons="{/Type}" >
<RadioButton text="YES" selected = "{Selected}" />
<RadioButton text="No" selected = "{Selected}" />
</RadioButtonGroup>
```

can some one pls advise on this .

Updating the model data code .

```
    var stermType = this.getView().byId("rbgTermType").getSelectedButton().getText(),                   
    sElecReg = this.getView().byId("rbgElecReg").getSelectedButton().getText(),                 
    sOpenReg = this.getView().byId("rbgOpenReg").getSelectedButton().getText(),                 
    sConfirmgdpr = this.getView().byId("idConfirmgdpr").getSelected(),                      
    oData = {};                 
    oData = {                   
    Term_Type: stermType,                       
    Electoral_Reg: sElecReg,                    
    Open_Reg: sOpenReg,                     
    Data_Protection_Confirm: sConfirmgdpr,                  
    };

    this.getView().setBusy(true);                   
    var that = this;                    
    var mParams = {                     
    success: function () {                          
    that.getView().setBusy(false);                      
    }.bind(),                   
    error: function (err) {                         
    that.getView().setBusy(false);                             
that.fnShowErrorMessage(jQuery.parseJSON(err.responseText).error.message.value)                     
    }.bind()  
};                      
this.getOwnerComponent().getModel().update(  "/PassportVisaBankCitizenshipDetailsSet(StudentObjid='',PassportNumber='',AccountNumber='')", oData, mParams);
this.getOwnerComponent().getModel().refresh(true);
```

Comment: Formatters and Expression Binding destroy Two-way data binding. Maybe you need to rework your odata backend. Instead of Y or N return boolean values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if the property `textType` has either value Y or N, you will need to use expression binding:

```
 <RadioButtonGroup >
   <RadioButton text="YES" selected = "{= ${textType}==='Y'}" />
   <RadioButton text="No"  selected = "{= ${textType}==='N'}" />
 </RadioButtonGroup>
```

The disadvantage is that you lose two-way when using expression binding. So you will need an onSelect Event handler (check event name in api docs)

If your property would be a **Boolean**, then you could just use

```
 <RadioButtonGroup >
   <RadioButton text="YES" selected = "{textType}" />
   <RadioButton text="No"  selected = "{=!${textType}}" />
 </RadioButtonGroup>
```

and be done

**UPDATE**: Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/iPirat/yhj3eabv/

I have put the thwo above Radio Button Groups in place, using the sample model with content

```
        {
          textType1: 'N',
          textType2: true
        }
```

The first {RadioButtonGroup} is working with {textType1} and an event handler is *necessary*

The second {RadioButtonGroup} is working with the boolean {textType2} and no event handler is needed. Binding does everything for you.

Comment: thanks it worked.  I have not tried the two way binding, changed my data type to boolean and will try saving the data and will check ..

Comment: thank you, the code is not working with the two way binding. any other advise ? I am using the above lines of code for two way binding on press event of my save button. edited my question with the code..

Comment: I added a jsfiddle example to demonstrate when you need an event handler, and when the two-way-binding is working without any event handlers

Answer (score 3):

the closest thing that you can do it treat 0 as Y and 1 as N.
here is a working example. https://jsbin.com/hutuvo/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>MVC</title>
    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" type="text/javascript"
            src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.ui.table"
            data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex">
    </script>

    <script id="oView" type="sapui5/xmlview">
    <mvc:View
    controllerName="sap.example.Controller"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns="sap.m"
    height="100%">
      <RadioButtonGroup selectedIndex="{/selected}">
        <RadioButton text="YES" />
        <RadioButton text="No" />
      </RadioButtonGroup>
      <Button text="Check" press="checkValue" />
      </mvc:View>
    </script>
    <script>
      sap.ui.define([ "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller", "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"],
                    function(Controller, JSONModel) {
        "use strict";

        var oPageController = Controller.extend("sap.example.Controller", {
          onInit: function() {
            this.getView().setModel(new JSONModel({
              selected: 1
            }));
          },
          checkValue: function() {
            alert(this.getView().getModel().getProperty("/selected") ? "NO" : "YES");
          }
        });
        return oPageController;
      });

      var oView = sap.ui.xmlview({
        viewContent: jQuery('#oView').html()
      });

      oView.placeAt('content');
    </script>
  </head>

  <body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
    <div id="content"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```